# Switch between sculpting brushes

Tags: workflow, sculpting

When sculpting I often want to switch between brushes. I find this a rather lengthy process. I have to open the sidebar and click on the icon and then click on the new brush I want to use. Is there a faster way to switch between brushes?

[image]

Comment: CTR+D toggles on\off Dyntopo. Dont thank me:)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are letter shortcuts for most brushes, <kbd>S</kbd> for smooth, <kbd>D</kbd> for brush/draw, etc. as well as number shortcuts (<kbd>1</kbd> for blob, <kbd>2</kbd> for brush, etc. Note that the number shortcuts depend on the order of the brushes in the menu, so 1 is always the first brush but necessarily blob)

For a full list, go to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> User Preferences > Input* and search for "brush":

[image]

And then scroll down to the *Sculpt* section:

[image]

There are options (for which brush to select) available if you expand a shortcut entry:

[image]

You can easily create your own shortcuts by

1. Pressing *Add New*
2. Set the shortcut actuator options (mouse or keyboard, modifier keys, shortcut key, etc.)
3. Type in `paint.brush_select` as the operator.
4. Select *Sculpt* as the paint mode (note that it will be grayed out until you select it).
5. Select the sculpt tool.

[image]

Also note that the *Smooth* brush can be activated without switching to another brush by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Answer (score 28):

<kbd>M</kbd> = Mask Painting
<kbd>K</kbd> = Snake Hook Brush
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> = Crease Brush
<kbd>C</kbd> = Clay Brush
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> = Flatten/Contrast Brush
<kbd>L</kbd> = Layer Brush
<kbd>G</kbd> = Grab Brush
<kbd>I</kbd> = Inflate/Deflate Brush
<kbd>P</kbd> = Pinch/Magnify Brush
<kbd>S</kbd> = Smooth Brush

<kbd>1</kbd> = Blob Brush
<kbd>2</kbd> = Clay Brush
<kbd>3</kbd> = Clay Strips Brush
<kbd>4</kbd> = Crease Brush
<kbd>5</kbd> = Fill/Deepen
<kbd>6</kbd> = Flatten/Contrast Brush
<kbd>7</kbd> = Grab Brush
<kbd>8</kbd> = Inflate/Deflate
<kbd>9</kbd> = Layer Brush
<kbd>0</kbd> = Mask

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> = Nudge Brush
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> = Pinch/Magnify Brush
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> = Rotate
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> = Scrape/Peaks
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> = SculptDraw
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> = Smooth
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> = Snake Hook
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> = Thumb

Graphic below, slightly outdated. Twist was renamed Rotate and Shift+Number hotkeys re-assigned.

[image: keybord shortcuts on the brush icons]

Current as of Blender 2.79a

Comment: If I use my installation I have brushes called Brush on Draw mode on shortcut 2 and Polish on shortcut Shift+4, There isn't Rotate brush, but there's Twist. While Factory settings don't have brush called Brush on Draw mode as well as Polish and Twist is called as Rotate. I didn't really think my brushes aren't default ones.

Comment: Here is another fast way: Enable Pie Menu: 3D Viewport Pie Menus and enable Sculpt Pie: Hotkey: 'W' in the settings. When sculpting just hit the W key to pick your desired brush. Some of them are nested.

Comment: Or Sculpt/Paint brush menus addon, Alt+V will be for brush settings

Comment: @BrysonJack in what version did they rename the brushes? That image is from 2.79b.

Comment: Seems these hotkeys do not work anymore in Blender 3.1