# Some sculpting brush hotkeys change the view rather than the brush

Tags: 3d-view, sculpting, shortcut

Hey everyone I am new to Blender and I've been watching sculpting tutorials on hotkeys for the sculpting brushes. A few of the brush shortcuts that involve pressing shift and a number for example (SHIFT+4 which I've read should be the scrape brush) change the view of the object instead of selecting a brush. I'm Curious is this some sort of setting that needs to be changed for the hotkey to work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> which is shortcut to rotate / roll the viewport camera.
Brush shortcuts are numbers on keyboard, not on Numpad. So to activate Sculpt brush from 10 to 20 you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+`number` on the row of keys above letters on the keyboard. In case of Polish brush this will be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

See for more brushes shortcuts [Switch between sculpting brushes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7310/switch-between-sculpting-brushes)

Comment: Im using blender on a Macbook pro laptop which only has one set of numbers on the keyboard besides the function keys.

Comment: @NoelBrevig if that means that you use Emulate Numpad then there doesn't seem to be another way to use digit shortcuts for brushes. There are other ways to achieve quick activating them via addons like Sculpt/Paint Brush menus or Pie menus which have menus opening on mouse for that however that isn't about shortcuts. What I meant in the answer is that behaviour of rolling viewport on pressing Shift+Numpad 4 is completely normal